# PHP unlink() issues

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir, unlink

Platform = Mac OS 10.8.5

Hi guys, I'm working on a php/mysql site. When I create a new user, my site creates a series of file folders to house information. My issue is when my user tries to delete his account, it will return a permissions error. I can temporarily fix this by changing the permissions of the biggest folder, but it all goes back to normal when I create a new user again. I am using XAMPP, which is located in the Mac Applications folder

This code:

```
unlink("Users/$clientUsername");
```

Returns this error:

> Warning: unlink(Users/Admin): Operation not permitted in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/POC-SQL/finalSite/deleteReciever.php on line 51

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the folder empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unlink — Deletes a file
```

and

```
rmdir() - Removes directory
```

You have a directory. You need to use rmdir, not unlink.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(file_exists("Users/".$clientUsername))
    unlink("Users/".$clientUsername);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following while creating the directory

```
$dir = "Users/".$clientUsername;
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777);
}
```

and for deleting that you should use recursive unlink() for deleting files and rmdir() for deleting folder.